# Ajax within a jsp page is not working on Internet explorer 9

Tags: jsp, jquery

I am working on web based application and i am creating an application using JSP using ajax to get data from Mysql database.
The code is executing fine on other browsers but it is not working fine on Internet Explorer-9.
how do i run it smoothly on internet explorer. Kindly help me in this regard.
the code is as following:

```
function getwords2(val)
  {document.getElementById("getcharter1").style.display ='block';
   if (val=="")
  {document.getElementById("getcharter1").innerHTML="";
  return;
}if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {       document.getElementById("getcharter1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }  }xmlhttp.open("GET","getvalue.jsp?ch="+document.FM.val.value+"&w1=2",true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the javascript console (using IEs developer tools, press F12 to open them)?

Comment: That's quite difficult to read. Also, have you considered using a JavaScript library that handles browser differences and abstracts away all this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give us more detail than "it does not work fine". That said, if you're having AJAX issues with IE9, it's almost certainly **HTTPS**-related.

https://www.parse.com/questions/internet-explorer-and-the-javascript-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

If this is working, you should add a meta-tag to downgrade into quirks-mode ie7